# Oracle error while running created procedure

Tags: oracle, plsql, procedure

I have Oracle database based on Hotel room stay overs. 
I have created a procedure Room_taken and I can't make it work.

**This is my SQL procedure code:**

```
CREATE
PROCEDURE Room_taken
(
v_guestID IN NUMBER DEFAULT NULL ,
v_stayfrom IN DATE DEFAULT NULL ,
v_stayto IN DATE DEFAULT NULL ,
v_roomID IN NUMBER DEFAULT NULL ,
v_paymentID IN NUMBER DEFAULT NULL ,
v_totalprice IN NUMBER DEFAULT NULL 
)
AS
v_nofrom DATE;
v_noto DATE;
v_idroom NUMBER(10,0);

BEGIN

BEGIN
SELECT Stay_from, Stay_to     
INTO v_nofrom, v_noto
FROM Stayover
WHERE ID_room = v_roomID;
IF NOT ( v_nofrom >= v_stayfrom
AND v_noto <= v_stayto ) THEN

BEGIN
INSERT INTO Stayover
( Stay_from, Stay_to, Total_price, ID_Room, ID_Guest, ID_Payment )
VALUES ( v_stayfrom, v_stayto, v_totalprice, v_roomID, v_guestID, v_paymentID );
END;
ELSE

BEGIN
raise_application_error( -20002, 'Room is taken!' );
END;
END IF;
END;
END;
```

**When I run procedure after entering following parameters:**

```
DECLARE
v_guestID NUMBER;
v_stayfrom DATE;
v_stayto DATE;
v_roomID NUMBER;
v_paymentID NUMBER;
v_totalprice NUMBER;
BEGIN
v_guestID := 1;
v_stayfrom := '17.01.2012';
v_stayto := '19.01.2012';
v_roomID := 1;
v_paymentID := 1;
v_totalprice := 300;

Room_taken(
v_guestID => v_guestID,
v_stayfrom => v_stayfrom,
v_stayto => v_stayto,
v_roomid => v_roomid,
v_paymentID => v_paymentID,
v_totalprice => v_totalprice
);
END;
```

**I got an error:**

```
Connecting to the database HOTEL.
ORA-01403: no data found
ORA-06512: at "HOTEL_ROOMS.ROOM_TAKEN", line 18
ORA-06512: at line 16
Process exited.
Disconnecting from the database HOTEL.
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are getting an error because a `SELECT INTO` construct must **return exactly 1 row** in PL/SQL. Your first select returns no row, so the `NO_DATA_FOUND` error is raised.

If there were 2 rows (for example a reservation in january, another in february), a `TOO_MANY_ROWS` error would be raised instead.

What you want to do instead is to make sure that if you insert, there will be **no overlap**. For example the following query will return all reservations during a period:

```
SELECT * 
  FROM Stayover 
 WHERE ID_room = v_roomID
   AND stay_from <= v_stayto 
   AND stay_to >= v_stayfrom
```

Notice that I compared `stay_from` to `v_stayto`, this is not a typo.

You could include the above query into your code with something like this:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE Room_taken(v_guestID    IN NUMBER,
                                       v_stayfrom   IN DATE,
                                       v_stayto     IN DATE,
                                       v_roomID     IN NUMBER,
                                       v_paymentID  IN NUMBER DEFAULT NULL,
                                       v_totalprice IN NUMBER DEFAULT NULL) AS
   l_nb_reservation NUMBER;
BEGIN
   SELECT COUNT(*)
     INTO l_nb_reservation
     FROM Stayover
    WHERE ID_room = v_roomID
      AND stay_from <= v_stayto
      AND stay_to >= v_stayfrom;
   IF l_nb_reservation > 0 THEN
      raise_application_error(-20002, 'Room is taken!');
   END IF;

   INSERT INTO Stayover
      (Stay_from, Stay_to, Total_price, ID_Room, ID_Guest, ID_Payment)
   VALUES
      (v_stayfrom, v_stayto, v_totalprice, v_roomID, v_guestID, v_paymentID);
END;
```

Now you will be able to reserve a room only once per period:

```
SQL> EXEC Room_taken(1, trunc(SYSDATE), trunc(SYSDATE), 1);

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed

SQL> EXEC Room_taken(1, trunc(SYSDATE), trunc(SYSDATE), 1);

begin Room_taken(1, trunc(SYSDATE), trunc(SYSDATE), 1); end;

ORA-20002: Room is taken!
ORA-06512: à "APPS.ROOM_TAKEN", ligne 16
ORA-06512: à ligne 2
```

Comment: I got it. I can enter new stay over data in table now, but with your code I can't raise 'Room is taken' error if there is already someone in same room at the same time... That's why I need this procedure. I'm still confused with how to do it.

Comment: @drazen you are inserting into the `NOCENJE` table and checking against the `STAYOVER` table. If you use the same table in both cases, you should get the "Room is taken!" error in case of prior reservation.

Comment: Sorry, my bad. I put wrong column in the code... It's working, thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 1):

Error Message
**ORA-01403**: no data found

Cause of Error

You tried one of the following:

1. You executed a SELECT INTO statement and no rows were returned.
2. You referenced an uninitialized row in a table.
3. You read past the end of file with the UTL_FILE package.

To show a suggested solution
Check this link
http://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/errors/ora01403.php